# camera and camera2 permissions in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

In my app android.hardware.camera2 works for api 21 22 but doesn't for lower versions and android.hardware.camera work till api level 20. What should I do to make it work for api level 15-22.

Answer (score 4):

> and android.hardware.camera work till api level 20

`android.hardware.Camera` works on all versions of Android. It is officially deprecated on API Level 21+, but it still works.

> What should I do to make it work for api level 15-22.

If "it" is `android.hardware.Camera`, it should work fine through API Level 22.

If "it" is `android.hardware.camera2.*`, it did not exist prior to API Level 21, and so without a time machine, you have no way of arranging for it to exist before it existed.

If "it" is your app, either use `android.hardware.Camera` for all devices, or use it only for the older devices and use `android.hardware.camera2.*` for newer devices. As the two APIs are not very similar, this will be a fair amount of work.